# web-scraping url with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape ATM and Branch address for all the banks for the url, but I am not able to do so.

URL="https://www.btpn.com/en/tentang-kami/contact-us/lokasi-cabang"

How can I extract them for all the locations, irrespective of my location selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make a simple request and grab the JSON with all the locations and then just filter by `type_code = ATM`. And you're done.

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.btpn.com/en/tentang-kami/contact-us/lokasi-cabang",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
data = requests.get("https://www.btpn.com/generate-branch", headers=headers).json()

for item in data["lists"]["btpn"]:
    if item["type_code"] == "ATM":
        print(item["address"])
```

This prints:

```
Jl. Margonda Raya No. 77 Depok
Jl. Indrapura No.1 EFG Surabaya
Jl. KH.Z.Mustofa 289 Tasikmalaya
Jl. Jend.Achmad Yani 618 Bandung
Jl. Anthony Rhebok No 41, Kel. Honipopu, Kec. Sirimau, Kota Ambon, Provinsi Maluku
Jl. Raya Bojonegoro RT 001/002 Babat,  Kel. Banaran,  Kec. Babat, Kota Lamongan, Provinsi Jawa Timur
Jl. Wolter Mongonsidi No.15 Bandar Lampung
Jl. Wolter Mongonsidi No.15 Bandar Lampung
Jl. Trunojoyo No. 1, Bangkalan
Jl. Tentara Pelajar No. 31 C - Banjar
...
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot :)